# Having trouble grabbing values from groupby

Tags: c#, linq, collections, group-by

So I am trying to grab two values from 2 different collections, the user collection which holds the names i need and the Post collection which holds the scores needed. I am trying to create a LINQ query that grabs all the post a user has posted, by comparing ID's, and then getting the lowest post score from that user. Here is what I have so far:

This prints what the 2 values I need but wont group them by Min value.

```
 var lowestQuery =
                from user in Assignment1.userDict
                from post in Assignment1.allPosts
                where user.Value.ID == post.AuthorID
                orderby user.Value.Name ascending
                group post.Score by new { user.Value.Name, post.Score } into scores
                select new
                {
                    name = scores.Key,
                    lowestScore = scores.Min()
                };
```

Basically just need the users lowest post but I am having trouble doing that with grouping two values. When I just group by user.value.Name I am able to get the list of names correctly but not the Score since it doesnt exist in scores that i created with the groupby statement. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: It would help if you include your classes. Try: `group post by new { user.Value.Name } into scores` then in your select you should be able to do`lowestScore = scores.Min(p => p.Score)`

Comment: @jcruz That didnt work since once I get into the select statement it only grabs values from the scores where i put the groupby

Comment: @GertArnold The data comes from the collections in the LINQ query. This is all C#

Comment: @HarryFischer Again, without knowing what your models look like we can only guess. Try my previous suggestion, using this: `group post by user.Value.Name into scores`. you should understand that the group returned will be your posts records so you should be able to get the Min score from there

Comment: @jcruz wow I missed that thanks. Can I ask where you got the 'p' from in the min(p=>p.score)?

Comment: It's called a predicate. Basically a pointer in Linq.

Comment: @jcruz Okay got it thanks man. Very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only interested in grouping by the user name, adjust your group by clause to group only by the user name and return post records (I renamed to posts since you are retrieving post records):

```
group post by user.Value.Name into posts
```

Then in your select you can use your `posts` group to select the `Min` score:

```
select new
{
     name = posts.Key,
     lowestScore = posts.Min(p => p.Score)
};
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Combining the users and the posts like this is going to have a bad performance. Since the two `from` clauses create nested loops, you will have a time complexity of `O(n^2)`. Better use a group join

```
var lowestQuery = from user in Assignment1.userDict.Values
    join post in Assignment1.allPosts on user.ID equals post.AuthorID into posts
    select new {
        name = user.Name,
        lowestScore = posts.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(p => p?.Score).Min()
    };
```

Note that the `Min` method will throw an exception if the collection is empty. `DefaultIfEmpty` creates `null` item. `p?.Score` returns a nullable value. It will be `null` if `p` is null. See: [Null-conditional operators ?. and ?[]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)